# Ajax reloading in Gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I'm using Gmaps4rails gem in my Rails 4 application. I have a geo data being loaded into the map, filtered by Ransack (search filter gem) and Kaminary (pagination filter gem). Both are working very well with AJAX loading.

However, I have no idea how to update the map when I change the information on the filters.

This is index.js.erb:

```
$('#sidebar').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@tweets) %>');
$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@tweets, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

This is the first time that I am using ajax in a Rails application.

Comment: You've all the toolset presented here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Js-Methods. First remove the previous markers, then add the new ones

Comment: Simply adding    

'handler.buildMap( {provider: mapOptions, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
     markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);    
   });'
was enough. Thank you, apneadiving. Your gem saved my life, good job.

Comment: After filtering the data, the first result is showed in double in the map. Do you know if this is a known issue?

Comment: removeMarkers first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @apneadiving suggested, the use of  [JS methods for Gmaps4rails](http://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Js-Methods)  will work, like this:

```
handler.buildMap( {provider: mapOptions, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.removeMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);       
});
    handler.buildMap( {provider: mapOptions, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);      
});
```

However, I found a more elegant solution, quite simple as well, using jQuery and a partial _map.erb.js containing the handler events. In the index.js.erb:

```
$('#map').html('<%= escape_javascript render("map") %>');
```